# Converting plain text csv rows into binary output

Tags: php, csv, binary

I have about 100GB of csv files. When I need to parse them, it takes > 2hours using a simple program. I have been thinking about converting plain text to binary:

Each integer field will be UINT32 field.
Each string field will be array of UINT8 fields. (ascii is enough in my case)

Each row will be left padded with its length (UINT32). Each field will be left padded with its length (UINT32).

I did this for testing purposes and when I treated every character as UINT32 I have got 4x more size than the normal csv file.

Is this a good thinking? Will I get less space usage, and faster parsing times, when I do this properly?

Comment: Is all yours digits in csv less than 9999? In that case you cloud replace uint32 to uint16, and you get 2x less size

Comment: I have some digits less than 2^16. I also have all my strings in ascii characters - they are kept as utf-8 by default I guess.

Comment: Do the files ever change? Are you re-parsing them over and over?